# Unable to detect change state ready for json

Tags: php, json, cordova

hi here's my code to connect phonegap to my database for login. The problem is that `(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)` cannot be detected. Here is my codes

```
     var username;
 var password;

function serverURL (){
    return"http://mp13.bit-mp.biz/princesszenn";
}


 function login(){
 username = $("#username").val();
 password = $("#password").val();
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var url = serverURL() + "/login.php";

 url += "?username=" + username + "&password=" + password;

 alert (url);
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
        {
        getLoginResult(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }else{
        alert("xmlerror")
        }
     }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
 }

function getLoginResult(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    if (arr[0].result == "1")
    {
    localStorage.setItem("username", username);
    localStorage.setItem('password', password);
    alert("Login Success!");
    window.location.replace("index.html");
    }
    else {
    alert("Error in User Name or Password");
    $("#username").focus();
    }
}
```

php page

```
    <?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

error_reporting(E_ERROR);

    $servername = "localhost";
    $dbusername = "seetoh88_mp13";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "seetoh88_mp13";

try{
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $password, $dbname);
    $username = $_GET["username"];
    $password = $_GET["password"];

    $query = "SELECT count(*) as found from testusers where username ='" . $username . "' and password = '" .$password . "'";

    $result = $conn->query($query);
    $count = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
    $json_out = "[" . json_encode(array("result"=>$count[0])) . "]";
    echo $json_out;

    $conn->close();
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    $json_out =  "[".json_encode(array("result"=>0))."]";
    echo $json_out;
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be detected"? Describe the problem better. Place a breakpoint - does it fire? If yes, then what are the statuses?

Comment: since `if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) ` is false, ` alert("xmlerror")` pops up. That's my error.

Comment: An error occurs on PHP-side. You can temporarily change your output in `catch` in order to output error message and stack trace, and then post it here.

Comment: Why aren't you adding `console.log(xmlhttp.readyState);` and `console.log(xmlhttp.status);` to you javascript part and check the status codes?

Comment: check status 0 too ```if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && (xmlhttp.status == 200 || xmlhttp.status == 0)```

Comment: Have you applied the `whitelist`?